# play mp3 files at designated duration

Tags: java, android, mp3, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to make an app that can play mp3 files at designated duration through *MediaPlayer*

for example:

**Start Time:** 00:42

**End Time:** 01:23

my question is:

-is it possible to designate the start and end time via textview at MM:SS format?

Thanks!!

Comment: - You can get string from text-view and format it with millisecond type and set to MediaPlayer.
- Noted: You should use ExoPlay with more powerful function better than MediaPlayer.

Comment: yes it is possible, have fun :)

Comment: Thank you @LouisNguyen , its my 1st time i hear this ExoPlay, i should keep this for future reference :)

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki yeah, thank you for your response too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes after initiating the MediaPlayer and loading the file , you can pause or stop the player after using specific time

```
while(mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
          if(mPlayer.getCurrentPosition() > 7254 && mPlayer.getCurrentPosition() < 7410 ){ 
              labelTxt.setText("Stop: " + mPlayer.getCurrentPosition() );
              mPlayer.stop();
              break;
          }
        }
```

Comment: i never thought that i have to use GetCurrentPosition, thank you for your solution @Shamitha Silva

Comment: @GioVanno If this doesn't work for you , you can down vote my answer. if this worked for you, you can accept my answer..and in the future when someone hit the same problem they will be directed to this answer. Since you are new to this I suggest you to study how SOF works

Comment: yeah man, it really works!
thank you, i still have much to learn :)
i've upvoted it

Comment: @Gio Vanno thanks..then you need to accept my answer.., that's how stuff works in StackOverflow. You need to learn about StackOverflow too. Upvoting is something else. accepting answers can be done clicking the 'right' mark..see you hv lot to learn

Comment: sorry my bad
i'll keep that in mind. Thak you for your guidance :)

Answer (score 0):

use This code

```
 MediaPlayer mp;

Runnable stopPlayerTask = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mp.pause();
    }};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText etStartTime = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_start_time);
    EditText etEndTime = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_end_time);

    String StartTime = etStartTime.getText().toString();
    String EndTime = etEndTime.getText().toString();

    long min = Integer.parseInt(StartTime .substring(0, 2));
    long sec = Integer.parseInt(StartTime .substring(3));

    long minEnd = Integer.parseInt(StartTime .substring(0, 2));
    long secEnd = Integer.parseInt(StartTime .substring(3));

    long startLong = (min * 60L) + sec;
    long endLong = (minEnd * 60) + secEnd;
    int starIntTime = (int) startLong;
    int endIntTime = (int) endLong;


    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.my_sound_file);
    mp.seekTo(starIntTime);
    mp.start();

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(stopPlayerTask, endIntTime);
}
```

Comment: i've thought to use 2 Textview, one for MM and one for SS
But it seems this code is much easier to understand,
gotta try this!
Thank you @jai khambhayta !!

Comment: your most welcome if this code is work for you than accept the anwser. Thank you.